# Android AutoComplete TextView with Custom ArrayAdapter and with Firestore not working

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

What I want to do is to populate AutoComplete TextView with the data from Firestore. I tried to retrieve data from Firestore and use it to create a Songs Object and store it in an ArrayList named songs. Those data are all Strings. You can see below. auto refers to the AutoComplete TextView.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        seekbar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        auto = findViewById(R.id.auto);
        current = findViewById(R.id.start);
        end = findViewById(R.id.end);
        lol.add("chey");
        lol.add("oi");
        db.collection("Songs_names").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    if (task.getResult() != null) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d("tag","msg " + document.getString("name"));
                            songs.add(new Songs(document.getString("name")));
                            Log.d("show objects","showed" + songs);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });
        songs_auto_adapter auto_adapter = new songs_auto_adapter(this,songs,this);
        Log.d("show songs","show" + songs);
        //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lol);
        auto.setAdapter(auto_adapter);
```

Then, I setAdapter to auto_adapter. You can see it below.

```
public class songs_auto_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Songs> {
    private List<Songs> songsFull;
    private Touch touch;
    public songs_auto_adapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<Songs> objects,Touch touch) {
        super(context,0, objects);
        songsFull = new ArrayList<>(objects);
        this.touch = touch;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d("View", "Creating Views");
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.songs_for_auto,parent,false);
        }
        final TextView textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.auto_text);
        Songs songs = getItem(position);
        if (songs != null) {
            textView.setText(songs.getName());
        }

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("clicked","It works" + position);
                touch.Touched(textView.getText().toString().trim());
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    private Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            List<Songs> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();
            if ( constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                suggestions.addAll(songsFull);
            }
            else{
                String filtertxt = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                for (Songs s : songsFull){
                    if (s.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filtertxt)){
                        suggestions.add(s);
                        Log.d("filtering","msg" + suggestions);
                    }
                }
            }
            results.values = suggestions;
            results.count = suggestions.size();
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            clear();
            addAll((List) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d("published","mmm" + results.values + songsFull);

        }

    };
```

The problem is when I typed in the AutoComplete TextView, nothing showed up. Then I used Log.d and I found out that publishResult is the one that gets called first and performFiltering is never called. See the message below.

```
D/published: mmm[][]
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=55KB, data=53KB
    After code cache collection, code=55KB, data=53KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
```

However, when I typed in the data manually, like this, songs.add(new Songs("sth")); ,the whole thing works. I cannot think of any solutions to solve this so I am here to ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with network request and it is not sequential. What it means - by the time adapter is created and set to the `auto` object the network request that returns a list of songs is not yet finished. Or maybe it has finished successfully, or maybe failed - no one knows.

Thus, from the `OnCompleteListener` you must make sure you update the list of songs **and adapter**. When the list is updated from `onComplete` method - your adapter knows nothing about that update. It does not watch changes in the array by itself.

You have to do a few things:

1. When network request is finished - make sure activity is not finished. Otherwise, you can end up with a crashing application (that will be hard to debug);
2. Make sure you notify the adapter about changes in the list of songs.

```
db.collection("Songs_names").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                // Step 1: if activity is no longer valid to use just skip this "task" response.
                if (isFinishing() || isDestroyed()) return;

                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    if (task.getResult() != null) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d("tag","msg " + document.getString("name"));
                            songs.add(new Songs(document.getString("name")));
                            Log.d("show objects","showed" + songs);
                            
                            // Step 2: songs are updated
                            adapter.updateList(songs);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Now you have to modify your adapter a little bit. A new method is added that accepts a list of songs and notifies adapter about the changes.

```
public class songs_auto_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Songs> {
    private List<Songs> songsFull;
    private Touch touch;
    public songs_auto_adapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<Songs> objects,Touch touch) {
        super(context,0, objects);
        songsFull = new ArrayList<>(objects);
        this.touch = touch;
    }

    public void updateList(@NonNull List<Songs> newList) {
        songsFull = new ArrayList<>(newList);
        clear();
        addAll(songsFull); // Adapter is now aware of the updated list
    }
    
    ...

}
```

Comment: There is one thing I don't understand. I created and set the adapter after the for loop so shouldn't the Arraylist , songs, contains all the elements already before it is set to the Adapter? So everything should work right? Is my thinking wrong?

Comment: You would be right if the code was executed sequentially. When you call Firebase for data you are actually performing a network request. Any network request is executed concurrently in a different than main (UI) thread. Because network requests take different time depending on many different variables (like broadband, type of connection,  ISP,  etc.) you cannot get the result immediately.  This is why you have `addOnCompleteListener`. This listener will be called when the network request completes and no one can precisely tell you beforehand when it will complete.  Network is unpredictable.